# Dynamic Memory Reallocation using realloc

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management

I am learning C++. I am trying to learn this dynamic memory allocation. In the below code I am trying to allocate memory using `malloc` and `realloc`.

```
int main (void)  {
  char *g = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 2);
  g = "ab";
  g = (char*) realloc (g, sizeof(char) * 200);
  strcpy (g, "cdefg");
  cout << g << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get **segmentation fault** error when I execute this code.

I've seen other SO threads recommending to use either `vector` or `new` instead of using above approach. Since, I am trying to learn this approach, so these answers does not applies to my question.

I've encountered a scenario where this approach will be well fitted, for example, If I am reading a raw text file using `ifstream.read` function and reading, let's say 1024bytes of it. Now, If I want to make sure I am not reading a word which is broken due to 1024bytes size I have to read further from that position using `ifstream.get` to reach until a space character is found. In this scenario, I need to adjust the buffer (which is of 1024) slightly more. My intention is to use `realloc` here to assign some more memory to it.

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: If you are learning C++, you should be using `new`, and `delete`.

Comment: TO ALL GURUS: Please consider answering my approach on reading the file part? Is this makes sense. Thanks in Advance

Comment: see answer by sharptooth, also I would like to mention that 2 characters are not enough to hold "ab" due to the null terminator

Comment: +1 to Sinan's comment, but perhaps std::vector or std::string would be even more useful to you as you can't reallocate new'd memory (look at the resize method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. First of all, you should not use `malloc` and friends if you are programming in C++.

```
char *g = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 2);
g = "ab";
```

Ooops. You just lost the 2 bytes of memory returned by the `malloc` call because now `g` points to the possibly read only location where `"ab"` is stored.

```
g = (char*) realloc (g, sizeof(char) * 200);
```

`realloc` can only be called on a pointer returned by an earlier `malloc`.

Even if you had passed a valid pointer to `realloc`, `realloc` may return NULL if the re-allocation fails. In that case, the memory previously allocated remains allocated but you would overwrite the only variable pointing to that memory making it impossible to free the earlier allocation. See [Having dynamically allocated an array, can I change its size?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/realloc.html) in the C FAQ list.

Also, note that `"ab"` requires three bytes of storage, not two. Finally, `sizeof(char)` is always and everywhere 1, so there is no need to use `sizeof(char)` in your `malloc` calls.

A correct **C** version of your program would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)  {
    char *tmp;
    char *g = malloc(3);
    if ( !g ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    strcpy(g, "ab");

    tmp = realloc (g, 200);
    if ( !tmp ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    g = tmp;

    strcpy (g, "cdefg");
    puts(g);
    return 0;
}
```

In the C++ version, you would use `string` rather than plan old C style character arrays.

See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627624/search-for-string-in-text-file-c/1627904#1627904) for an example of how to reallocate a buffer to read complete lines for the second part of your question.

However, note that code is also **C** and I am sure there are better ways of doing what you want in C++. I just do not know enough of the C++ standard library to give you a correct solution in C++.

Comment: Can explain me the solution for your last para? Why realloc can't be used if it is safely handled.

Comment: If the code above is to be called correct, it should check the return value of `malloc` and ensure is not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks Sinan, It was a great help!!

Comment: This is a *really* nice answer

Answer (score 9):

In

```
g = "ab";
```

you make `g` point to a chunk located in static storage, not on heap, then in

```
g = (char*) realloc (g, sizeof(char) * 200);
```

you try to call `realloc()` with that address belonging outside the heap. This is undefined behaviour and crashes your program. You can call `realloc()` only with addresses returned by `malloc()` or `realloc()` (or null pointer).

The problem is that you meant this:

```
strcpy( g, "ab" );
```

but mistakenly wrote this:

```
g = "ab";
```

The former would work allright - `g` is initially set to an address returned by `malloc()`.

There's one more problem - you allocate too little memory initially. You should allocate an extra byte for the null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the line:

```
g = "ab";
```

sets the `g` pointer to another location altogether. It does not copy the contents. You lose track of the original location and when you use `g` in `realloc`, you'll be `realloc`ing the wrong pointer.

Replace the line with:

```
strcpy(g, "ab");
```

Of course, you'll need three bytes to store the string and the terminating `'\0'` character.

That said, `malloc` and `realloc` are C style things. If you are using C++, you should try `new` and `delete` and probably use `string` type to store strings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the original malloc to 3 to include the null terminator, and use strcpy to set the contents to "ab"

```
char *g = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 3);
strcpy(g , "ab");
```

Answer (score 0):

Re the second part of your question:

Consider using `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<char> g;
g.resize(1024);
// fill up g
// decide you need another hundred bytes at the end of g
g.resize(1124);
// memory will automatically be released when g goes out of scope
```

Note that to pass a pointer to the start of the buffer, you will now have to say `&g[0]` instead of simply `g`.

Comment: the problem is, if i've to read data from a file ifstream.read takes only char* not std::string. So, you cannot skip the above approach... Is it right?

Comment: ? I am suggesting using a `std::vector<char>`, not a `std::string`.  `&g[0]` is a `char *` which can be passed to `ifstream::read()`.  I'm not sure I understand your question.