# Finding string in HTML file with C

Tags: c

I have a HTML file that I've retrieved through curl and I wanted to find certain strings in the file so that I could analyse whether I have received the response I expected.

Here's the function I'm using to search for my string:

```
int find_str(FILE *infile, char *str)
{
    char tmp[512];
    while(fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), infile) != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(tmp, str) != NULL)
        {
            printf("found %s in file\n", str);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't Find %s in file!\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

and it's called as follows:

```
if(find_str(html_file, "<h1>Hello World</h1>") == 1)
{ ... }
```

First, the string is never found even when it is present. Second, this function is called in another if statement if the first should fail, but while watching execution in the debugger, it completely skips the while loop. No garbage values are given. If I watch the tmp array, the values seem normal, although they seem to have been encoded.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: With that function, if your search string sits around 512 byte boundaries in the file, it won't match because you only check 512 byte blocks. You can load the whole file into memory instead.

Comment: If you are calling find_str more than once, you'll need to call rewind(html_file) between calls.

Comment: @Atle Nice guess! I think this is the problem

Comment: @Atle post an answer.

Comment: @CharlieBurns that solved one issue but it still never finds the string

Comment: @Ciaran Read Atle's comment

Comment: @Atle that seems as if that's my problem, but how can I load the whole file into memory

Comment: @Atle, OP is using fgets, not fread. If a line is longer than 512, that's an issue. But not a boundary issue if the lines are shorter than 512 and the search string does not contain a newline. Am I missing something?

Comment: What to do with that answer now...

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the file has that string (use cat)? Have you tried making a test file with only the search string?

Comment: @Nick Yes, I'm positive I think Atle is on to the issue, the string could be cut in half by the boundary and so its wouldn't be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that function, if your search string sits around 512 byte boundaries in the file, it won't match because you only check inside 512 byte blocks.

To fix this issue, you can load the whole file into memory instead. This also has an advantage on performance if you decide to search multiple times, as you won't have to do I/O every time.

This should work to read a file into memory:

```
fseek (infile, 0 , SEEK_END);
int filesize = ftell (infile);
rewind (infile);

char *whole_file = malloc(filesize+1);
if (!(filesize == fread(whole_file, filesize, 1, infile))) {
    // ERROR
}
whole_file[filesize] = '\0';
```

Comment: how would i load the file into memory ?

Comment: @Ciaran do you understand what is problem?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes I now understand the issue but I'm not to sure on how to implement the solution

Comment: @Ciaran Not sure check [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1627904/1673391)

Comment: I edited in some fresh code here, does it work?

Comment: I finished the error checking-lines, funny how the code worked with half an if-statement.

Comment: And =/== mistake, fixed that. Have a look.

Comment: @Atle i didnt copy and paste it I just typed it in thats why it worked :)

Comment: forgot to add in the error if error check to make sure the sizes match and it says it doesnt here are the sizes `filesize=26292`
`fread = 25770`

Comment: Refer to the manuals on how to use error checking-functions, this is the Linux manual: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread. Or new question.